# How to DROP TABLE in PostGIS using PyQGIS

Tags: postgis, pyqgis, qgis-3

I want to drop a table from PostGIS using PyQGIS, but it doesn't seem to work even though SELECT statements work fine. This is what I currently have:

```
uri = QgsDataSourceUri()
uri.setConnection("localhost", "5432", "database", "user", "password")
sql = 'DROP TABLE schema.table'
uri.setDataSource('', '(' + sql + ')', 'geom', '', 'id')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not have to use PyQGIS:

```py
import psycopg2
  
conn = psycopg2.connect(database="data", user='postgres', password='yourpassword', host='localhost', port='5432'
  
conn.autocommit = True
cursor = conn.cursor()
  
sql = '''drop table if exists test.builtup; '''
  
cursor.execute(sql)
  
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/executing-sql-query-with-psycopg2-in-python/

Comment: Thank you for your help! This works perfectly! I didn't know about psycopg2 prior to your response.

Comment: That is not going to work with proxy settings though as it by-passes QGIS' settings.

Comment: Well it worked for OP